# Showing the string in XML edit text

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I need to add a value in EditText.But I doesn't need to show the output with the help of TextView.

Comment: Please be clear.

Comment: Erm, it's quite hard to be clear without a picture.

Comment: But I had figured out the problem. Thanks :D

Comment: now its edited @user3548900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clear about where to show it! But if you want to show a Toast, you can try this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), edtText.getText.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you want to show in logcat, you can try this:

```
System.out.println("you entered: "+edtText.getText.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't want a toast nor a logcat, I'm just simply want a editText that can show my output. I had solved the problem, thanks any way and so sorry about my question is not clear.

Comment: ok great @user3548900 :)